# this package ha no dependencies meaning?

Tags: c#, .net-core

i am searching some package in nuget for .netcore 3.1 i found this package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager/) but it show in dependencies section "their is no dependencies"  i didn't understand this meaning .

1. this dependencies is no more availabel for .net core 3.1
2. or this dependencies not require and it work fine without this one also .

or some different meaning??

which one is correct ??

Comment: In general, when reporting an error, it's best to copy/paste the error text so that it appears in your question exactly as the tool shows it

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, please accept it. Otherwise, please edit your question so it's clear where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "Dependencies" means other NuGet packages which the package requires to function.

In this case, it means that `Unofficial.Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager` is a standalone package and doesn't require any other NuGet packages.

Note that the linked NuGet page has no means of discerning if you intend to use this package with .NET Framework, .NET Core, or a .NET Standard library. That information isn't in the URL or anywhere on the page.

If the library is compiled for .NET Standard, then it will work in .NET Framework and .NET Core. Some libraries, however, are only compatible with .NET Framewok, so they won't work if you're using .NET Core.